# Сделать activity, которую нельзя закрыть

Tags: android, service, activity

Доброго времени суток. 
Как сделать activity, которую нельзя закрыть.  Девайс используется как измерительное устройство, пользователь не должен получить доступ к другим функциям.  
Проверяю в сервисе запущена ли activity и если нет запускаю, но на некоторых телефонах после нажатия кнопки домой можно успеть попасть в звонилку, на некоторых в настройки   и при этом activity не вотсонавливается

```
            while (!Setting.getPassword(getApplicationContext()).equals(CryptoUtil.getHash(Setting.SALT1 + Setting.pseudoID+Setting.SALT2) )){

                AudioManager aManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                aManager.setRingerMode(aManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                if (!isRunning(getApplication())) {
                    Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyActivity.class);
                    dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
                }
            }

        public boolean isRunning(Context ctx) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) {
            if (ctx.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(task.baseActivity.getPackageName()))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: сделай приложение как лончер, будет при загрузке открываться и не свернёшь кнопкой HOME

Comment: правда, если пользователь доберется до настроек, то он сможет сменить лончер.

Comment: я очень надеюсь, что без рута ваше вредоносное ПО работать не будет...

Comment: @metalurgus тогда к вредоносному по причислим электронное меню в ресторанах, приложения кладовщиков в связке с 1с и многие другие, где на руки работнику/клиенту выдаются девайс а лезть куда то ни ни ни

Comment: @gadfil, это является вредоносным ПО чисто по определению вредоносного ПО...

Comment: @metalurgus, по технической составляющей соглашусь, технически  ресивер на смс потенциальный шпион, но для этого и есть разрешения .... хотя да, пользователи их редко читают (

Answer (score 1):

В android 5.0 появился специальный API для реализации kiosk mode приложений — ["Screen pinning"](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#ScreenPinning).

Активировать его для своего приложения можно двумя способами:

- Через настройки: безопасность — блокировка в приложении, там выбрать свое приложение
- Вызвав [Activity.startLockTask()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startLockTask%28%29).

Более подробное описание можно посмотреть в статье [Implementing Kiosk Mode in Android - Part 3: Android Lollipop](http://sdgsystems.com/blog/implementing-kiosk-mode-android-part-3-android-lollipop)

Если вам нужно для android более ранних версий, то можно посмотреть статью ["How-To Create a Working Kiosk Mode in Android"](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/). В ней автор собрал огромное количество хаков и обходных путей для приложений на android 4.0

Для решения проблемы с кнопкой home, можно задействовать режим car mode и временно переопределить home:

```
    <activity android:name="sdg.example.car_mode.CarModeDemo"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:launchMode="singleInstance" > <!-- Don't run multiple copies -->
        <!--  Have the Home key give us control instead of the Home app -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.dock_home" android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!--  Become the Car Mode activity -->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_DOCK" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Источник: [Implementing Kiosk Mode in Android - Part 1](http://sdgsystems.com/blog/implementing-kiosk-mode-android-part-1)